# Guice get all bindings with specific @BindingAnnotation

Tags: guice

I want to scan somehow the bindings after module configuration and obtain the implementations that implement a specific interface. These implementations are marked using a @BindingAnnotation.

The definitions are the following:

```
public interface Provider {}

@BindingAnnotation @Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD })   
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    public @interface EchoService {
}


class Module extends AbstractModule {
    void configure() {
        bind(Provider.class).annotatedWith(EchoService.class).toInstance(new Provider(){...}
        ....
    }
}
```

In clases:

```
@Inject @EchoService Provider provider;
```

I don't want to use additional Multibinding configuration in the Module definition to keep the definition simple.

Comment: Do you really have a type called `Provider` that isn't a Guice/javax `Provider`?  That's somewhat confusing...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Injector.getAllBindings](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#getAllBindings--) to retrieve all the bindings the `Injector` knows about.  Then you can use [Key.getAnnotationType()](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Key.html#getAnnotationType--) to find just the ones with your particular `@BindingAnnotation`.